# How should I write and unmarshal a byte64 encoded value in YAML

Tags: go, yaml, marshalling

Part of my Yaml file

```
rules:
- action:
    count: {}
  name: rulenumbertwo
  priority: 123
  statement:
    bytematchstatement:
      fieldtomatch:
        singleheader:
          name: foobar
      positionalconstraint: CONTAINS
      searchstring: [103, 105, 122, 122, 98, 117, 122, 122]
```

The above comes out as the corresponding ASCII string ("fizzbuzz") for the searchstring value. But how can I write it human-readable format? The [manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_ByteMatchStatement.html#WAF-Type-ByteMatchStatement-SearchString) says that the searchstring should be "automatically" converted but it throws an error if I do not write it as an array of ASCII codes.

My code (trying to unmarshal it, which works if I write the array directly but it is not human-readable):

```
d := &wafv2.UpdateRuleGroupInput{}
err = yaml.Unmarshal(buf, d)
```

I would like to write the YAML simply as follows

```
rules:
- action:
    count: {}
  name: rulenumbertwo
  priority: 123
  statement:
    bytematchstatement:
      fieldtomatch:
        singleheader:
          name: foobar
      positionalconstraint: CONTAINS
      searchstring: fizzbuzz
```

Or possibly use a template (but why when it should be easy)

```
searchstring: {{ convertStringToByteArray "fizzbuzz" }}
```

Comment: What error does it throw if you use a string rather than a byte array?

Comment: @Christian `cannot unmarshal !!str fizzbuzz into []uint8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `ByteMatchStatement` which contains the SearchString doesn't have anything declared on it customizing the way it loads from YAML, so it can't load a `[]byte` from a YAML scalar. The manual you link describes the semantics of the type, but does neither define how the data is stored (depending on use-case, it does make sense to store something that is a `string` to the user as `[]byte`) nor how it can be loaded from YAML. Generally, (de)serialization tends to expose facts about the data model that would be implementation details otherwise, and this is what hits you here.

The simple fix would be to declare some `type SearchStringType []byte`, use it for the `SearchString` field and declare a custom `UnmarshalYAML` method there to handle the conversion to `[]byte`. However, that is not possible in your code since you don't have control over the types.

One possible albeit somewhat crude fix would be to pre-process the YAML input:

```golang
type LoadableUpdateRuleGroupInput wafv2.UpdateRuleGroupInput

func (l *LoadableUpdateRuleGroupInput) UnmarshalYAML(n *yaml.Node) error {
    preprocSearchString(n)
    return n.Decode((*wafv2.UpdateRuleGroupInput)(l))
}

func preprocSearchString(n *yaml.Node) {
    switch n.Kind {
    case yaml.SequenceNode:
        for _, item := range n.Content {
            preprocSearchString(item)
        }
    case yaml.MappingNode:
        for i := 0; i < len(n.Content); i += 2 {
            if n.Content[i].Kind == yaml.ScalarNode &&
                n.Content[i].Value == "searchstring" {
                toByteSequence(n.Content[i+1])
            } else {
                preprocSearchString(n.Content[i+1])
            }
        }
    }
}

func toByteSequence(n *yaml.Node) {
    n.Kind = yaml.SequenceNode
    raw := []byte(n.Value)
    n.Content = make([]*yaml.Node, len(raw))
    for i := range raw {
        n.Content[i] = &yaml.Node{Kind: yaml.ScalarNode, Value: strconv.Itoa(int(raw[i]))}
    }
}
```

By using this new subtype when unmarshaling, the YAML scalar value of `searchstring` will be transformed into the YAML sequence node you would have written. When you load the YAML node, it will then properly load into `[]byte`:

```golang
d := &LoadableUpdateRuleGroupInput{}
err = yaml.Unmarshal(buf, d)
```

This code requires `gopkg.in/yaml.v3`, `v2` does not give you as much control over unmarshaling.

Comment: Thank you! Meanwhile, I did it with a template which seemed to work just replacing to value with its byte array `searchstring: {{ "fizzbuzz" | convert  }}`